# Cypress does not exit after completing tests in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, cypress

I'm looking to run a Cypress test as a job in a Gitlab pipeline. I'm using the cypress/included:12.8.1 docker image since it matches the version of Cypress I'm using. I know this Cypress image is set up with an entrypoint of `cypress run`. The pipeline job runs and looks like it tries to run the `cypress run` command with `--config` then throws an error. I think I need to pass a config file to the command but I can't figure out how. I have a cypress.config.js file in my Gitlab repo but Gitlab doesn't provide a way for a pipeline job to access a repo file within a script section.

UPDATE 1:
I have partially solved the issue. I was able to get Cypress to run in the pipeline job. The Cypress documentation is not very helpful. I had to override the default entrypoint by adding `entrypoint: [""]`. This stops `cypress run` from automatically running when the cypress image is started which was causing the error. `cypress run` was running automatically and looking for a configuration file that wasn't there.
Now the issue I have is the pipeline job doesn't exit when the cypress test completes. I'm fairly sure it is due to the next server running in the background. I tried adding Xvfb commands as described in the [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Xvfb) but I get an error.

UPDATE 2:
I've narrowed down what the issue could be. I turned on debugging mode when running cypress in the pipeline like so: `DEBUG=cypress:server* npx cypress run --headless --config-file cypress.config.js -c video=false`. Using Xvfb didn't make any difference so I removed those commands.

This is the latest output from the Cypress pipeline job after the tests have finished:

```
cypress:server:cypress about to exit with code 0 +8s
cypress:server:browsers browsers.kill called with no active instance +2s
cypress:server:util:socket_allowed allowed socket closed, removing { localPort: 57714 } +3s
cypress:server:util:socket_allowed allowed socket closed, removing { localPort: 57704 } +1ms
cypress:server:socket-base socket-disconnecting transport close +241ms
cypress:server:socket-base socket-disconnect transport close +0ms
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

This my Gitlab YAML for the Cypress job:

```
---
cypress tests:
  image: 
    name: cypress/included:12.8.1
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: e2e-tests
  interruptible: true
  dependencies: []
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - .npm
      - cache/Cypress
  rules:
    - exists:
      - cypress.config.js
  artifacts:
    # Store cypress screenshots as artifacts on job failure only
    when: on_failure
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/cypress/screenshots
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/cypress/videos
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run build --omit=dev
    - npm run start &
    - DEBUG=cypress:server* npx cypress run --headless --config-file cypress.config.js -c video=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some testing and some research I figured out how to solve the issue. It looks like the issue is with Electron and similar to this previously reported [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25568#issuecomment-1404253879) in GitHub. Instead of running cypress in headless mode I ran it with chrome and the pipeline job exited successfully. This is the command that worked: `npx cypress run --browser chrome --config-file cypress.config.js`.

When I upgraded Cypress 12.8.1 to 12.9.0 and used headless mode the error did not occur in the Gitlab pipeline. It looks like the Electron issue was finally fixed with version 12.9.0. Either Chrome or Electron will work in a Gitlab pipeline using a cypress included image and version 12.9.0.